# I can not install generator-jhipster-uml to generate entities

Tags: java, jhipster

I am trying to generate entities (Java classes) from https://jhipster.github.io/jdl-studio/ , I create `jhipster-jdl.jh` file and I start to generating entities. Firstly according to the documentation I use this

`yo jhipster:import-jdl my_file.jdl`

to generate my entities, but this statement generate some `.json` files and that's all, but I need java classes, DTO, Services and others files. My friend tell to use this:

`yo jhipster-uml my_file.jdl`

But after that I get this errors:

```
Error jhipster-uml .\jhipster-jdl.jh

You don’t seem to have a generator with the name “jhipster-uml” installed.
But help is on the way:

You can see available generators via npm search yeoman-generator or via http://yeoman.io/gene
Install them with npm install generator-jhipster-uml.

To see all your installed generators run yo without any arguments.
```

So then I tried to install this generator but I get other error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\M\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\
npm-cli.js" "install" "generator-jhipster-uml"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-jhipster-uml
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'generator-jhipster-uml' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

What should I do? I did everything what was describe in documentation. I am using Jhipster version 3 not 4. Should I migrate upper version to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`yo jhipster:import-jdl my_file.jdl` should import your JDL and generate JSON files and frontend/backend files for the entity.  If it fails, please open an issue.

`jhipster-uml` is not a yeoman-generator, so you run it without `yo` before it.  That's also why installing `generator-jhipster-uml` fails.  To install, [follow the instructions in the docs](https://jhipster.github.io/jhipster-uml/#install):

```
 npm install -g jhipster-uml
```

If you haven't started a project yet, I would recommend upgrading to v4.  You can still use Angular 1 for now if you need to.